# Create a windows service from a compiled app

Tags: c++, c, windows, service

I want to create a service from my compiled C/C++ code with `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015`. I compiled my code and create a service with `sc.exe` from app executable. My code consists of an endless loop which writes a simple string to a static file within time intervals. After creating a service and reboot, it seems that service is stopped automatically. The executable works fine when directly run.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

void write_txt_file(string file_name, string input) {
    /*
    write a string to a specific txt file
    */
    FILE *f = fopen(file_name.c_str(), "a+");
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", input.c_str());
    fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        write_txt_file("C:\\...\\Desktop\\out.txt", "Writing...#" + to_string(i));
        Sleep(5000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here is the command I use to create a service:

```
sc.exe create My_service binPath= "<path to executable>" start= auto
```

and the output of `out.txt` file is:

```
Writing...#0
Writing...#1
Writing...#2
Writing...#3
Writing...#4
Writing...#5
Writing...#6
Writing...#7
Writing...#8
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of @Aconcagua and [this reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus) I found a simple code to just make my code compatible with windows service. In the function `ServiceWorkerThread` you need to just put your loop inside the while block. The service can be stopped safely.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


SERVICE_STATUS        g_ServiceStatus = {0};
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_StatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE                g_ServiceStopEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain (DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler (DWORD);
DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread (LPVOID lpParam);

#define SERVICE_NAME  _T("My Sample Service")


using namespace std;

void write_txt_file(string file_name, string input) {
    /*
    write a string to a specific txt file
    */
    FILE *f = fopen(file_name.c_str(), "a+");
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", input.c_str());
    fclose(f);
}


int _tmain (int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Entry"));

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] = 
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION) ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher (ServiceTable) == FALSE)
    {
       OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned error"));
       return GetLastError ();
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Exit"));
    return 0;
}


VOID WINAPI ServiceMain (DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    DWORD Status = E_FAIL;

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Entry"));

    g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler (SERVICE_NAME, ServiceCtrlHandler);

    if (g_StatusHandle == NULL) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: RegisterServiceCtrlHandler returned error"));
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory (&g_ServiceStatus, sizeof (g_ServiceStatus));
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    /* 
     * Perform tasks neccesary to start the service here
     */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Service Start Operations"));

    // Create stop event to wait on later.
    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent (NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: CreateEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent) returned error"));

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = GetLastError();
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 1;

        if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        goto EXIT; 
    }    

    // Tell the service controller we are started
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    // Start the thread that will perform the main task of the service
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread (NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Waiting for Worker Thread to complete"));

    // Wait until our worker thread exits effectively signaling that the service needs to stop
    WaitForSingleObject (hThread, INFINITE);
    
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Worker Thread Stop Event signaled"));
    
    
    /* 
     * Perform any cleanup tasks
     */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Cleanup Operations"));

    CloseHandle (g_ServiceStopEvent);

    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }
    
    EXIT:
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Exit"));

    return;
}


VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler (DWORD CtrlCode)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Entry"));

    switch (CtrlCode) 
    {
     case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP :

        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP Request"));

        if (g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
           break;

        /* 
         * Perform tasks neccesary to stop the service here 
         */
        
        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 4;

        if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }

        // This will signal the worker thread to start shutting down
        SetEvent (g_ServiceStopEvent);

        break;

     default:
         break;
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Exit"));
}


DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread (LPVOID lpParam)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));
    int i = 0;
    //  Periodically check if the service has been requested to stop
    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {        
        /* 
         * Perform main service function here
         */
        write_txt_file("C:\\...\\out.txt", "Writing...#" + to_string(i));
        //  Simulate some work by sleeping
        Sleep(3000);
        i++;
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows services are not just simple executables such as you wrote one, but need to follow a specific pattern how to communicate with the operating system. You can find all necessary information at [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685969(v=vs.85).aspx) site, additionally, any good search engine will reveal innumerable examples of how to write one (such as [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus)).

Alternatively, you can use a windows service wrapper (you might try [this one](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/) – need to say, though, that I did not evaluate it – or search for another appropriate one).

Side note: Why did your executable stop execution? Well, because it did not follow above mentioned pattern, i. e. did not inform the OS appropriately about its state (see the links) and thus was shut down (killed) again by the OS as it considered your "service" inoperable...

Comment: Thanks. I can't find any simple example to make a code service compatible. The examples try to create a service from the code itself, but I don't want to make service when running my executable I just want to make it compatible with windows service.

Comment: @MasoudR. Sorry to have to tell you: You cannot get your executable "compatible to windows service" without implementing it as windows service... If you don't want to do so, try the service wrapper alternative. The wrapper behaves as a service just as required by Windows and will start your executable when time comes. And when the service is to be stopped, it will kill your application and do the normal service shutdown for you. How will it kill? Different options, so look at the documentation to the wrapper of your choice...

Comment: [Here](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-services-srvany.html)'s another service wrapper. Name appears familiar to me, might have used it once *long, long* ago...

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `nssm` which is a wrapper too. I'm hoping someone put a simple example on my code or I will put it by myself :D.

Comment: @MasoudR. Looks nice, too... All you should need to do now is running `nssm install <name for your service> <your exe> <optionally: some start parameters>` from command line, according to nssm's [documentation](http://www.nssm.cc/commands). If you want to see how the service gets actually started, peek at windows registry (`regedit`) and look for `HOT_KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/services/<name you gave before>/ImagePath`...